# Best bandwidth tests to use in a pinch?

Tags: networking, bandwidth, testing

I see many tools that have been discussed for 'proper' bandwidth monitoring and testing - but I am wondering what people use 'in a pinch'?  Particularly on systems that they may not easily have admin privileges on?

I am mainly looking for Internet tests.  Speedtest.net works in most cases, but it relies on flash - not something that is always available, particularly when rdc'ing into servers.

Anyone have reliable equivalents that will run very lightly?  I know they won't give reliable data like ipcop, ntop, ipaudit, bandwidthD when properly configured, but sometimes we just want to make sure things are connected...

Comment: I was going to suggest speakeasy.net/speedtest/ but they use flash as well.

Comment: I use speedtest.net as well (love the eye candy graphics) but I just tried DSLreports.com and the latter shows about 1/2 the speed and I suspect more realistic (I got 7.7 Mb/s and 18 Mb/s thru DSLreports and Speedtest, respectively)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like [DSLReports](http://www.dslreports.com/stest).  They've consolidated several speedtests.  Good for quickly going to and finding one if your computer isn't liking one of the tests.  There must be over 200 different sites to try.  The IPhone one looks HTML only.  Unless I'm missing something.

Answer (score 5):

My preference is http://testmy.net it's fast does not require flash, and easy to remember.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you're looking for an extremely unofficial way of testing your bandwidth, that will also NOT require you to install flash or Java... then **CNET** bandwidth Meter will help you there: [**http://reviews.cnet.com/internet-speed-test/**](http://reviews.cnet.com/internet-speed-test/)

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to machines on both sides of the connection, I'd look into [Iperf](http://iperf.sourceforge.net/).  From the [Wikipedia Article on Iperf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iperf):

> Iperf is a commonly used network testing tool that can create TCP and UDP data streams and measure the throughput of a network that is carrying them. Iperf is a modern tool for network performance measurement written in C++.

You run the tool on two machines, and iperf will give you information on the bandwidth between them.

Answer (score 1):

[Speed of Me](http://speedof.me) Is my suggestion....

It is built on html5 technology and doesn't need flash or java plugins.

http://speedof.me

Comment: Are you the author of the site? I like the idea, and the graph is great looking - I just wish that it would have the bandwith to do any actual testing (I get 500kB/s max here, and I'm on a 100mbit pipe)

Answer (score 0):

I often test download speed by downloading a linux install ISO from a "nearby" server that I know has more bandwidth then the host I'm testing.

Upload bandwidth can be harder to monitor, but as it's generally less important I generally don't worry about it.

Answer (score -1):

Speakeasy has a good one when you are ok using Flash.

http://speakeasy.net/speedtest/

Comment: This is the one I generally use first.

Comment: -1 - He was rather explicit about speedtests that don't use Flash.

Answer (score -1):

I've used this in the past when there hasn't been flash support:
http://www.ispgeeks.com/wild/modules/Bandwidth_Meter_DSL/initialmeter.php

My biggest problem with most of these sites, particularly the non-flash ones is that they never seem to run long enough to be accurate.

(Sorry, missed the part about no flash)
After speakeasy, I would use
http://www.speedtest.net/